# how to Establish connection between Cloud Function And Firestore DB in Python?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

> I want to Import the data from my firestore to Cloud Function and do some manipulation in python language. So far I have studied the documentation but it is not much helpful [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).
> The problem is this-->

```
 import firebase_admin
 from firebase_admin import credentials
 from firebase_admin import firestore
 //Use a service account
 **cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount.json')**
 firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
 db = firestore.client()
```

> Where will I store this file "path/to/serviceAccount.json", I can only see two files on my cloud function called **Main.py** and **requirement**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snipped you are showing applies to using the firestore library on a local server/your machine. In that case, you have to create a JSON key file for a service account that you want to use for your requests. I recommend you familiarize yourself with [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) first. There is also a section on keys.

However, you are running the code in a cloud function. In that case, the service account you specify as *runtime service account* when creating the cloud function is used for any request as default and you don't have to use a key file. So you can basically just start [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#initialize) and the `Client` will be initialized using that service account by default. **Important:** the service account has to have the respective permissions to use/query firestore (see my first link under service account permissions).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, Actually for a newbie, there is no clear documentation and I wasted so much time on searching. Can you please direct me on how can I update the data in my remote config from my cloud function? I have written Jason in my remote config. I want to push data from my cloud function to remote config.

Comment: do I have to call remote Config API in my cloud function? Please keep in mind both remote config and cloud function are at the same account.

Comment: I'm not familiar with remote config. You can have a look at the documentation and if there is a python library for using that API. However, I don't think this is in the scope of your question, so it'd be better to ask a new one.